# How to change the behavior of append for a class attribute

Tags: python, attributes, append, decorator, simpy

I am using a python package (simpy), which provides several classes that I need. One of the classes is called Event, with the following constructor:

```
def __init__(self, env):
    self.env = env
    """The :class:`~simpy.core.Environment` the event lives in."""
    self.callbacks = []
    """List of functions that are called when the event is processed."""
    self._value = PENDING
```

At many different places in the code, objects are added to the callbacks of an event, using the `Event.callbacks.append` method.

What I need is a new class (which i call Zombie), which is actually an Event class, except for three modifications. Firstly, it should contain an additional attribute `Zombie.reset_callbacks` and a method `Zombie.reset()` to reset `Zombie.callbacks` to a previous state (this is why I need the `Zombie.reset_callbacks` attribute. All of this, I can do by subclassing `Event`.

However, for this to work, I would need that everytime `Zombie.callbacks.append(x)` is called, `x`is not only appended to `Zombie.callbacks`, but also `Zombie.reset_callbacks`. I have been looking into decorators to see if I could do this, but I do not see the light at the end of the tunnel. I currently feel this is not possible, or I might be looking in wrong directions.

Is such thing possible (changing the append behavior for a class attribute) in Python? And if so, how?

Thanx for your effort in advance!
B.

Answer (score 1):

Whoops. Misread this. If you're really dedicated to maintaining this interface, you can define a helper class.

```
 class SplitLists(object):
     def __init__(*append_methods):
         self._append_methods = append_methods

     def append(self, value):
         for method in self._append_methods:
              method(value)

a = []
b = []
split_list = SplitLists(a.append, b.append)
split_list.append(1)
a  # [1]
b  # [1]


class Zombie(Event):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(Zombie, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self._real_callbacks = []
         self._reset_callbacks = []
         self.callbacks = SplitLists(self._real_callbacks.append, 
                                     self._reset_callbacks.append)
```